# How can I merge the bands for each ID to create two multi-band TIFFs in R?

Tags: r, function

I have 16 separate raster files, named by ID and band, for 8 bands and 2 IDs. How can I merge the bands for each ID to create two multi-band TIFFs? Here are my data:

```
    dput(rastlist)
    c("7398_b10_new.tif", "7398_b2_clip.tif", "7398_b3_clip.tif", 
"7398_b4_clip.tif", "7398_b5_clip.tif", "7398_b6_clip.tif", "7398_b7_clip.tif", 
"7398_pan_new.tif", "9609_b10_new.tif", "9609_b2_clip.tif", "9609_b3_clip.tif", 
"9609_b4_clip.tif", "9609_b5_clip.tif", "9609_b6_clip.tif", "9609_b7_clip.tif", 
"9609_pan_new.tif")
```

I managed to do it this for the first 8 elements of my list. Here's how:

```
setwd("mydir")

#first import all files in a single folder as a list 
rlist <- list.files(path = "mydir", pattern='.tif$', all.files=T, full.names=F)

#substract the  first 8 raster of the list
n = tail(rlist,8)

#stack layers
rstack = stack(n)

#substract the first element of the list
one = tail(n, 1)

#get the first 4 letters of the first element of a list (to be used as raster name of the raster stack)
rexport = substr(one, 1, 4)

writeRaster(rstack, filename = rexport, options = "INTERLEAVE=BAND", overwrite = T, format = "GTiff")
```

Basically, what I want is to create a function that performs the above code every 8 raster.

Comment: If raster ID is the prefix of every raster file name, can you use your exsiting code within a loop that iterates over names?

Comment: I've tried many times but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop over each unique ID:

```
for(ras in unique(substr(rastlist, 1, 4))){
  rlist <- list.files(path = "mydir", pattern=paste0(ras, '*.tif$'), all.files=T, full.names=F)
  rstack = stack(rlist)
  writeRaster(rstack, filename = paste0(ras, ".tif"), options = "INTERLEAVE=BAND", overwrite = T, format = "GTiff")
}
```

Or, the same thing, but as a function, like you say in your question:

```
stacker <- function(ras){
  rlist <- list.files(path = "mydir", pattern=paste0(ras, '*.tif$'), all.files=T, full.names=F)
  rstack = stack(rlist)
  writeRaster(rstack, filename = rexport, options = "INTERLEAVE=BAND", overwrite = T, format = "GTiff")
}

rass <- unique(substring(rastlist, 1, 4))

lapply(rass, stacker)
```

Comment: I am trying to follow your suggestions but I'm not getting the right result. Both in the `for loop` and `function` I'm getting an error `Error in .local(x, ...) : no filenames supplied`. Why is that?

Comment: It sounds like you aren't finding any files with `list.files()`. What do you get if you run `rlist`?

Comment: `rlist
 [1] "7398_b10_new.tif" "7398_b2_clip.tif" "7398_b3_clip.tif" "7398_b4_clip.tif" "7398_b5_clip.tif"
 [6] "7398_b6_clip.tif" "7398_b7_clip.tif" "7398_pan_new.tif" "9609_b10_new.tif" "9609_b2_clip.tif"
[11] "9609_b3_clip.tif" "9609_b4_clip.tif" "9609_b5_clip.tif" "9609_b6_clip.tif" "9609_b7_clip.tif"
[16] "9609_pan_new.tif"` I am getting the raster files. I've tested this but I can't understand why the `loop` or the `function` can't read the files

Comment: It's a good idea to run line-by-line to debug. I just tested this on my machine, and I got it to work by fixing a couple simple typos. (1) Make sure `path=mydir` is correct. Note that if you use `path="mydir"`, that's the string rather than the variable. (2) Update to `pattern=paste0(ras, ".*.tif$)`.

Comment: It worked! Great job Skaqqs, thanks a lot.